# Hibernate - named query not known

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a weird problem. I googled many solutions in the internet, but no one was helpful.

I have this simple method to get information from my database:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByHash");
query.setString("hash", hash);
query.setDate("hash", new Date());
List<?> list = query.list();
User user = (User) list.get(0);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And this returns me an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query
>   not known: User.findByHash    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1407)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
>   at wroproject.UserConnection._getUserByHash(UserConnection.java:44)
>     at wroproject.UserConnection.(UserConnection.java:26)
>     at wroproject.Main.main(Main.java:19)

The top of the User.java file looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "wroproject", schema = "public")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByHash", query = "SELECT \"user\".* FROM \"user\" LEFT JOIN session on \"user\".id = session.user_id WHERE session.hash = :hash AND date_time_terminate < :date")
})
public class User implements Serializable {...}
```

My fibernate.cfg.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wroproject</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WroProjectPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>wrocproject.db.User</class>
    <class>wrocproject.db.Email</class>
    <class>wrocproject.db.Session</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wroproject"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have on line 44 and 26 of class UserConnection

Comment: In 24-th line I run a method with above code. In 44-th I have this `Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByHash");`

Comment: Even if I change `User.findByHash` to `User.findAll` I still have `Named query not known` error.

Comment: Can you confirm that User.java imports "org.hibernate.annotations.Entity" and not "javax.persistence.Entity"?

Comment: Yes, User.java imports "org.hibernate.annotations.Entity"

Answer (score 2):

It is odd to me that you are using both a hibernate.cfg.xml and a persistence.xml file to configure hibernate. If you are using hibernate-core, then use hibernate.cfg.xml, if you are using hibernate-entitymanager, use persistence.xml.

Since you are using SessionFactory, your persistence.xml is probably being ignored for configuration. Since persistence.xml is where you specify what your entities are, I suspect none of your entities are being mapped. You can test this by just trying to load the entity without using a stored procedure:

```
session.get(User.class, id);
```

Also you could turn on logging and see what entities are being registered when you create a SessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

In the query are this parameters:

```
hash AND date_time_terminate
```

Change :

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByHash");
query.setString("hash", hash);
query.setDate("hash", new Date());
```

By:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByHash");
query.setString("hash", hash);
query.setDate("date_time_terminate", new Date());
```

Comment: I'm thinking you have `query.setDate("date", new Date())` in your mind. Sadly there is the same error.